# maven php plugin for phpunit failing to load

Tags: php, maven, phpunit

Walked through the install steps over at http://www.php-maven.org/tags/2.0.0/php-lib-5min.html ...

Using: Maven 3.0.3, 
PHP 5.3.13,
maven-php-plugin 2.0.0, 
phpunit 3.6.10.

The project has only the stub LibraryClass.php and LibraryClassTest.php dropped in by the project builder call.

When i run 'mvn package' in the last step of their guide i'm getting:

Caused by: org.apache.xbean.recipe.MissingAccessorException: Unable to find a valid setter method: public void org.phpmaven.phpunit.impl.PhpunitSupport360.setSingleInvocation(...)

Looking at the javadoc for PhpunitSupport360, that method doesn't exist.  As everything was installed by maven (and pear) i'm not sure what's going on.  The guide says to user Maven v3.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it loads a wrong plugin. For me it works.

You shoud ensure that it really loads the correct plugin versions. If you try to change the php-maven plugin version (f.e. to 2.0-SNAPSHOT) you should use the corresponding php-parent-pom and use the property ${phpmaven.plugin.version} as version. or simply remove any version number from the php-maven plugins because the version numbers are managed by the php-parent-pom.

You may look at the output of mvn help:effective-pom to see what is going on and what versions for the plugins are used.